# Quarkus App failing to start on minikube in prod profile

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, kogito

When I am trying to start the quarkus app on minikube using the following command:

./mvnw clean package -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true

Pod is failing to start and when I look for the logs I see the following trace.

2023-10-10 12:15:48,985 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection$ConnectEvent.handle(PlainHttpConnection.java:128)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:957)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:912)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:912)

I tried checking the Kogito index service but not sure if its getting connected.

How will I know why its throwing Connection Refused?

Comment: Your application has been trying to connect to another service (or database) that is not started,  in another network, or behind a firewall.
Check why the other service is not available in the first place.